# top CPU does not sum for all CPUs

Tags: top

From my box:

```
root@arrakis:/tmp# top 
top - 09:53:14 up 28 days, 15:10, 15 users,  load average: 0,59, 0,64, 0,67
Tasks: 391 total,   2 running, 386 sleeping,   1 stopped,   2 zombie
%Cpu0  :  4,5 us,  2,4 sy,  0,0 ni, 93,2 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu1  :  5,7 us,  0,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 93,7 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu2  :  4,7 us,  4,3 sy,  0,0 ni, 90,6 id,  0,3 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu3  :  2,4 us,  9,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 87,7 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu4  :  3,0 us,  4,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 92,3 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu5  :  1,7 us,  1,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 97,3 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu6  :  1,4 us,  6,4 sy,  0,0 ni, 92,2 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu7  :  9,1 us,  9,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 81,2 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:  32569700 total, 29484408 used,  3085292 free,   483096 buffers
KiB Swap:  7811068 total,   195860 used,  7615208 free. 19405416 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                        
15237 mgarcarz  20   0 4146332 2,164g 2,105g S 208,4  7,0   6261:10 VirtualBox                                                                                                                                     
30077 mgarcarz  20   0 3270276 1,210g  76436 S   9,3  3,9   1668:14 firefox
```

We can see VirtualBox has 209% of CPU, but looking per core all CPU0-CPU7 has 80-90% idle (which means that only around 70% of one core is consumed in total). So that does not sum. Where is that 200% CPU consumed ?

Thanks, Michal

Comment: Do you actually have more than 8 cores?  It might only show 8 cores but you have more that add up to the 208%.

Comment: I have exactly 8 cores (4 with HT).